# Codeblocks comment out whole block

Tags: c++, codeblocks, comments

I am using a Codeblocks IDE for C++ and I tried googling it, but could not find the answer.

How do I comment out a block of code in Codeblocks?
For example in Eclipse its ctrl+7.

Comment: Code::blocks is an IDE, not a compiler.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A quick google gives me [this page](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Keyboard_Shortcuts), which says it's Ctrl + Shift + C.

Comment: the fact that the words "block" and "code" are quite common in programming certainly doesn't help google... I did `"code::blocks" block comment`, which worked well enough.

Answer (score 25):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>   to comment selected block

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>   to uncomment .

Answer (score 5):

You can do a box comment with `/*` at the start and `*/` at the end. It'll block out everything in between.

i.e.

```
/*This is part of a block comment. 

This is still part of it

This also part of it */
```

If you just highlight the code you want to comment out and go to Edit --> Box-Comment. It'll do it all for you.

Answer (score 5):

Shortcut to Comment highlighted code:   `Ctrl + Shift + C`

Shortcut to Uncomment highlighted code:     `Ctrl + Shift + X`

By the way, You can go with [this](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Keyboard_Shortcuts) link and you can search whatever shortcut you want in codeblocks.

Answer (score 3):

First, select the code. After that, press `Ctrl + Shift + C`.

Answer (score 1):

There are various functions involving that sort of thing, they're all in the Edit menu